# Performance difference between join and select from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Is there any difference, mainly performance-wise between using from multiple tables:

```
SELECT widgets.* FROM widgets, manufacturers 
WHERE widgets.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.id
AND manufacturers.location = 2
```

and `JOIN`ing:

```
SELECT widgets.* FROM widgets
JOIN manufacturers ON widgets.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.id
WHERE manufacturers.location = 2
```

I am asking specifically regarding MySQL/MariaDB if that makes any difference.

Comment: it's just a syntactic difference. the query plan SHOULD be identical internally, but you should NOT be using the "lazy" `t1,t2,t3`-type syntax anymore. Use the explicit `JOIN` version. it's clearer and easier to understand - especially when someone else comes along and needs to figure out if you're doing an inner/outer, left/right-type join.

Comment: Thats what I thought, appreciate the insight and have always used the explicit `JOIN`, I had just come across a solution on stack overflow yesterday that used the non join version.